# why cur.execute('select id from credit where kp_order_id = "A15268964292124586"') is empty?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, pymysql

the test code works :
from common import mysqlDB

```
mysql = mysqlDB.MySQLCommand(****)
sqls = ['DELETE FROM `credit_queue_record`;', 'DELETE FROM `fund_queue_record`;', 'DELETE FROM `installment_bill`;', 'DELETE FROM `kporder_queue_record`;', 'DELETE FROM `order_info`;', 'DELETE FROM `transaction_record`;']
mysql.executeSql(sqls)

sql = 'select id from credit where kp_order_id = \"A15268964292124586\"'
print(mysql.querySql(sql))
```

when I used it in python unittest, the return value is null:

```
class one2oneTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):    

        #
        # empty the tables
        #
        self.mysql = mysqlDB.MySQLCommand(*********)

        sqls = ['DELETE FROM `credit`;', 'DELETE FROM `credit_queue_record`;', 'DELETE FROM `fund_queue_record`;', 'DELETE FROM `installment_bill`;', 'DELETE FROM `kporder_queue_record`;', 'DELETE FROM `order_info`;', 'DELETE FROM `transaction_record`;']
        self.mysql.executeSql(sqls)

    def test_one2one(self):
        sql = 'select id from credit where kp_order_id = \"A15268964292124586\"'
        id = self.mysql.querySql(sql)
        self.assertIsNotNone(id, msg='id 不应该为空')
```

query sql:select id from credit where kp_order_id = "A15268964292124586"
None

## F

### FAIL: test_one2one (**main**.one2oneTest)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "one2one.py", line 55, in test_one2one
    self.assertIsNotNone(id, msg='id 不应该为空')
AssertionError: unexpectedly None : id 不应该为空

the class querySql() is :
    def querySql(self,sql):
        print("query sql:" + sql)

```
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(sql)

        row = self.cursor.fetchone()
        return row
    except:
        print(sql + ' execute failed.')
        self.conn.rollback()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add time.sleep(5) before query. Maybe I am foooooooolish.